# I can't unlock my ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, email

I recently decided to get the ios8 update for my ipad but after the update, the ipad came up with the sign that I had to plug it up to iTunes. So I plugged it up to iTunes and it said I needed to restore my iPad to get the update. My screen was stuck on the same sign that showed connecting to iTunes so I didn't have a choice but to choose to restore and update. After I updated it, it was restored but there was an activation lock. I didn't recognise the email that is came up with that it was linked to. It was a personal iPad that I used for school so I was the only one who ever used it. I'm unable activate it because I don't know what email it is, even more the password to it. I have kept my receipt for buying the iPad and everything and it also said to try and remove it from Find my iPhone which I did but it still says I need to activate it with the email I don't recognise. Should I just bring it an Apple specialist? I'm sorry if this is very confusing but I have a lot of school documents on it and I have so much work to do for upcoming exams. I'm sorry if it sounds shifty because I don't even recognise the email it requires but please if there is anyone out there who can help me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: start at http://forgot.apple.com - assuming you set up an iCloud account of some sort

Answer (score 1):

Send a note to the email address saying "Hey, did we accidently swap iPads? I seem to have yours - where is mine?" If in fact it is locked with someone else's AppleID, I think you are out of luck. These theft prevention types of systems are intentionally hard to bypass. If you can bring your receipts and the device to an Apple store, they might be able to assist you. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a few things you can do

**1) Start at [iforgot.apple.com](http://iforgot.apple.com)**

This may be your apple ID, but just an old one you don't recognise. I've had this problem with other friends before where they don't remember how/when they made that account. So thats the best place to try

**2) Contact the email address**
If you don't know who it is, try and get in contact with them and see if you can resolve the issue that way. A mixup might have occurred somehow or anything else. Send them an email and see what happens.

**3) Get in contact with Apple**
If both options above haven't worked, and you have proof of purchase, take the iPad to a local genius bar at an Apple store. They might be able to help you given proof of purchase. Calling them *may* help but I highly doubt it. Most likely they will ask you to book an appointment at a genius bar so they can physically see a form proof of purchase and the device itself. Anyone can use photoshop to make fakes these days.

---

The activation lock is a last resort for a stolen iPad, so it's meant to be impossible to bypass to prevent someone from using a stolen iPad - making it meaningless to steal if it doesn't function. I will be entirely honest with you, this question does seem extremely shifty...
But if the device is indeed yours, and you have proof of purchase, take it to a genius bar. They might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Something doesn't sound right, as if you restored somebody else's backup. I would take it to a Genius Bar or at the very least call Apple and explain your situation.

Admittedly, it does sound shifty...